# Can't add <div> to the Tiptap

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, editor, tiptap

I am using Tiptap as a rich text editor, and i need to insert some html on it, to render on front end.

**example:**

```
<div>
    <p style="margin-top: 30px; text-align: center;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XYUz7LA_d.webp?maxwidth=520&shape=thumb&fidelity=high" style=" border-radius: 30px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px 0px 20px; border: 3px solid #544AF2; background-color: #e9eef2; ">
    </p>
    <div style=" background-color: #544AF2; padding: 12% 10% 8%; margin: -10% 6% 5%; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; ">
        <div>
            <p style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">
                                                     title test 1
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:30px;text-align:center;">
                                                                text test 1
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the editor Tiptap is not reading the code, just simple things like `<p>hello <b>there</b>!!!!!</p>`